# Debugging POST request in Netbeans

Tags: java, debugging, servlets, netbeans, web-applications

I have a Java web application I'm trying to debug. It works when I try to debug GET requests, but it doesn't work on POST. Did the following steps:

1. Started Apache Tomcat in debug mode
2. Set up my break point
3. Run Netbeans in Debug mode

I'm sending the POST request from a terminal, and in the debug HTTP Server Monitor it receives this request and parses it correctly. However, it doesn't stop at my break point.

Here is my servlet:

```
public class RegisterServiceServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter pr = response.getWriter();

        String serviceAddress = request.getParameter("address");
        String deviceIdString = request.getParameter("device_id");
        String serviceName = request.getParameter("name");

        if ((serviceAddress == null) || (deviceIdString == null){
            ....
        } else {
            ....
        }
}
```

My break point is on the "if" statement. What am I missing?

**EDIT 1: Added a screen shot with the HTTP Server Monitor. I make the POST request using curl from a terminal. Also, tested again with a GET request by changing the doPost to doGet and it works.**

[image]

**EDIT 2: Tested this on my Windows Laptop and it works!. Previously, I was debugging the project in a Virtual Box set up as follows:**

java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca, apache-tomcat-8.0.15, netbeans-8.0.2

On my Windows laptop I have:

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment jdk1.7.0_80, apache-tomcat-8.0.23

Clearly it is an environment problem.

Comment: Maybe you get an exception before the if statement? Set the breakpoint in the first line of your method.

Comment: How do you know it parses it correctly?

Comment: @Jens just checked this, and still doesn't stop.

Comment: @Roman C Check the HTTP Server Monitor. It looks like the request (i.e., all the parameters) are passed correctly.

Comment: @Andrei Have you deployed the latest version of your code?

Comment: @Jens yes I did also I checked with a GET request from another servlet and works. I will try to change this to a GET request and see if it works.

Comment: Http Server Monitor? Hmm, could you post a screenshot?

Comment: Added a screenshot with my Http Server Monitor. Also, please see the update.